# SonarQube + Jenkins Error 500

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

I have successfully integrated SonarQube and Jenkins using the SonarQube plugin for Jenkins. The Sonar analysis seems to be successful, but I cannot see the results on the Sonar dashboard. Here is the stacktrace:

```
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git
INFO: 6 files to be analyzed
INFO: 6/6 files analyzed
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=343ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=12ms
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: JavaCpdBlockIndexer is used for java
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=20ms
INFO: Calculating CPD for 6 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 65ms, dir size=39 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 187ms, zip size=23 KB
INFO:         ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 4.083s
INFO: Final Memory: 50M/385M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=helloworld&projectName=Simple%20Java%20project%20analyzed%20with%20the%20SonarQube%20Runner
at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:34)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.failIfUnauthorized(BatchWsClient.java:99)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:69)
at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.upload(ReportPublisher.java:172)
at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.execute(ReportPublisher.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.publishReportJob(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:64)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.executeOnRoot(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:51)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:86)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:72)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60)
```

When I click on the link it says

```
 {"errors":[{"msg":"HTTP method POST is required"}]}
```

I think the solution is to reconfigure SQ  so it directly uses the target URL, but how do I do that?

Comment: 500 means server error, look in *<sonarqube_install_dir>/logs/sonar.log* to see which error occurred on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

In my sonar it doesn't put the binary data to MySQL so I change

max_allowed_packet      = 16M  to

#max_allowed_packet      = 256M

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error and Nicolas' comment about checking the sonar.log helped me diagnose the problem. I was running this on Windows as a Windows Service, and the user of the process was set to the default Local Service and so it was looking for a temp folder under C:\Windows\System32. I changed the user account to an actual user account and that solved the problem.

If the error in the log is about unable to find the temp folder, try checking the user account that Sonar is running under.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, the sollution was that the host parameter was given with 'http' not 'https' format, that was causing redirect which was loosing the POST information

Answer (score 0):

It worked to me: 
In Jenkins, go to Global Tool Configuration and look for SonarQube Scanner block. 
Activate it. The error will be gone.

https://gabrielscavassa.wordpress.com/2016/07/21/jenkins-sonarqube/